# Got this error ='MultinomialNB' object has no attribute 'coef_'

Tags: coefficients, multinomial

'MultinomialNB' object has no attribute 'coef_'

i tried this=

```
#adj = list(zip(model.coef_[0], cv.get_feature_names()))
```

but got the error saying that =multinomialNB object has no attribute coef_

Answer (score 1):

.coef_ for multinomialNB has been deprecated since version 0.24 and it has been removed in 1.1 (renaming of 0.26).

By reading https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7233 you get that coef_ is just taken from the .feature_log_prob_ method. So basically if you use:

```
list(zip(model.feature_log_prob_[0], cv.get_feature_names()))
```

you should get the same result.

If you are wondering why .coef_ has been deprecated, you can find your answer in this issue: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2237 i.e. "The coef_ and intercept_ on MultinomialNB don't behave like other linear models because they contain probabilities even in the binary case. They should contain log-odds ratios."